# ETL Job Execution on kettle

Tags: java, pentaho, kettle

Executing Kettle jobs at the command line I am facing below error.

**Kettle error :-**

```
c:\FTP_Uploads\Test\data-integration>Kitchen.bat /file "C:\FTP_Uploads\Test\ETL\ACHProcessJob.kjb"
EBUG: Using JAVA_HOME
EBUG: _PENTAHO_JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_07
EBUG: _PENTAHO_JAVA=C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_07\bin\java.exe
icked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Xmx512M
Error: Could not find or load main class  -Djava.ext.dirs=.;C:\FTP_Uploads\Test\data-integration\lib;C:\FTP_Uploads\Test\data-integration\libext;C:\FTP_Uploads\Test\dat
a-integration\libext\JDBC;C:\FTP_Uploads\Test\data-integration\libext\webservices;C:\FTP_Uploads\Test\data-integration\libext\spring;C:\FTP_Uploads\Test\data-integratio
n\libext\commons;C:\FTP_Uploads\Test\data-integration\libext\web;C:\FTP_Uploads\Test\data-integration\libext\pentaho;C:\FTP_Uploads\Test\data-integration\libext\mondria
n;C:\FTP_Uploads\Test\data-integration\libext\salesforce;C:\FTP_Uploads\Test\data-integration\libswt -Djava.library.path=C:\FTP_Uploads\Test\data-integration\libswt\win
32 -DKETTLE_HOME= -DKETTLE_REPOSITORY= -DKETTLE_USER= -DKETTLE_PASSWORD= -DKETTLE_PLUGIN_PACKAGES= -DKETTLE_LOG_SIZE_LIMIT= org.pentaho.di.kitchen.Kitchen .file C:\FTP_
Uploads\Test\ETL\ACHProcessJob.kjb
```

Comment: it seems like some files are missing. Please check if all data-integration is installed properly !!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
Kitchen.bat -/file="C:\FTP_Uploads\Test\ETL\ACHProcessJob.kjb"
```